# Not able to resolve EnableSessionState is set to true error in all DNN pages

Tags: asp.net, session, web-config, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have already research in Google about this  error but couldn't succeed and finally posted here.

I have downloaded my live website, database and integrate it in my local environment. I can only see Home Page but not able to see other pages. I’m facing below error in my all other pages.

I think **default.aspx** is the home page in DNN so it is working fine but not other pages which are render dynamically from DNN tables.

**Error Exception:**

> Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration.

**Event Log Table Message:**

> DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the <configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> section in the application configuration. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the <configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> section in the application configuration.
>         at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Session()
>         at DotNetNuke.Framework.CachePageStatePersister.Save()
>         at System.Web.UI.Page.SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(Object state)
>         at System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState()
>         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I had take reference from from [this link](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/495844/scope/posts/pageloadexception-session-state-can-only-be-used-when-enablesessionstate-is-set-to-true) and update like below in my web config file but I missed all pages of my website and does not able to see Home Page also. **EventLog** table showing me same error message as I posted in my question.

**Update web config like below:**

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
```

...

```
 <httpModules>
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"  />
```

...

```
<pages validateRequest="false" enableViewStateMac="true" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" enableSessionState="true" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before The Error:**

I have added my DNN website as Sub Directory in my local IIS server so my access URL has become `http://localhost/WebsiteName/`. For some of the reason in DNN core libraries it doesn't work with sub directory and faced error `enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive` in my local computer but On live, It was installed as `Default Web Site` on IIS Server.

**Error Resolved:**

Just replace my website from sub directory to `Default Web Site` in IIS Server and it works. I didn't get any error. So, now access URL become `http://localhost/`

I checked both websites set in same application pool as well as same dotnet framework version but sub directory website doesn't work and when I set it to in the place of default IIS website it works.

**For visitors of this post:**

If you don't able to solve this error, you can go with Cathal Connoly (A DNN MVP)'s answer. Refer this [link](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/108/postid/518421/scope/posts) for more information.

It appears that if you change the page state persistence this will resolve it (http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Content/Dn...) , or else enable set enableSessionState to true in your web.config